# Execute a Jar with Wildcard in Path

Tags: java, selenium, jar

I have an application that launches a jar file.  However, the jar has the version number in the name and will change every few months.  I'm looking to write this so I don't have to update the application's code every time the jar is changed.  I've tried using * for a wildcard, but I get:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Selenium\vendor\selenium-server-standalone-\*.jar
```

The command I'm running is:

```
java -jar C:\\Selenium\\vendor\\selenium-server-standalone-*.jar
```

When I put in the version number, the jar launches successfully.  Is there anyway to use a wildcard here?

Comment: why does the tag have Selenium

Comment: This is to launch the Selenium server.  I thought someone may have encountered this if they were automating launching their Selenium server.

Comment: Why not rename the .jar when you download it to a name that remains constant? There's nothing in Selenium that requires the .jar to have the name `selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.jar`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about windows, the best you can do here is to write a minimal batch file that greps the file name and puts it right there

**for unix**: you could do something like

```
java -jar *.jar
```

this works well in unix

Comment: I'm using this on both Windows and Linux, so I'll try on the Linux box and see if this works.

Comment: But what happens if he has more than one version of the jar in the same directory? I would say maybe using an environment variable to set the version then do 

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-$VERSION.jar, no?

Comment: well I didn't mean to use exact this *.jar, this is just an example @Aca

Answer (score 0):

I think a very simple way of doing this, and have it working in Windows and Unix is by setting an environment variable with the version you want to execute, and just like Jigar says, create a simple batch file that executes the correct version.

So if you set

```
$VERSION=1.0 and
$JARPATH = C:\\Selenium\\vendor
```

you could easily make a batch file that does

```
java -jar $JARPATH\\selenium-server-standalone-$VERSION.jar
```

You can then have many versions of the JAR file, in the same directory, and just by changing the variable you can execute the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may add all jars from a specific folder:

- replace -jar with -cp
- replace file-name with *

In your example that would be :

`java -cp C:\\Selenium\\vendor\\*`