# Can run a jar file without knowing the jar file name

Tags: java, spring, sh

Can any one tell how to run a jar file using java -jar command without knowing the Jar's full name, I know the prefix but the version of the jar file is dynamic,so I don't want to update my sh for every deplolyment

```
 #!/bin/bash

PROJECT_HOME=/opt/services/testing-batchp
PROJECT_JAR=batch-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ -f /etc/environment ] && . /etc/environment

nohup java -jar -Dspring.config.location=${PROJECT_HOME}/config/ ${PROJECT_HOME}/${PROJECT_JAR} $1 $2 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I just modified the variable PROJECT_JAR="batch*.*-SNAPSHOT.jar" but its not working.
Here the version of the jar will change in each deployment.
Please help

Comment: You can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589278/execute-a-jar-with-wildcard-in-path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below approach for executing script without mentioning the jar's release version.

```
 #!/bin/bash

PROJECT_HOME=/opt/services/testing-batchp
PROJECT_JAR=batch-*.*.jar
[ -f /etc/environment ] && . /etc/environment

nohup java -jar -Dspring.config.location=${PROJECT_HOME}/config/ ${PROJECT_HOME}/${PROJECT_JAR} $1 $2 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Make sure that only one valid jar is there in the deployment folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the dynamic variable as below;

```
PROJECT_JAR=`ls -r batch*.*-SNAPSHOT.jar | head -1`
```

This must do the job. However, please note the ticks(`) enclosing the command to enable substitution.